# LNPopupController and Tableviewcell Swipe

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, uitableview

I'm using this framework https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController for presenting view controllers as popups (like Spotify player) in swift project.

I added a Tableview to the controller but i have problem, LNpopup dismiss when i try to delete a row with swipping.

I want to be able to swipe to delete rows in Tableview, without dismiss LNPopup (please swift code)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of LNPopupController.

The framework exposes the gesture recognizer used for the swipe. You should use the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail(_:)` API to add gesture recognizers from your tableview and/or cells.

Comment: Can i get an example of implementing this please @LeoNatan I'm having the same issue here on my end

Comment: @LeoNatan can you show us an example please

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky I'm not sure what example you'd like without any code context. It's just simple gesture delegate stuff. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate